# Return recordset from function in classic ASP

Tags: function, asp-classic, adodb, recordset

I'm at a loss on how I can return a readable recordset from a function in classic ASP.

This is what I came up with, but it's not working:

```
Response.Clear
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

Dim Count

Set Count = Test

Response.Write Count.Fields(0).Value


Function Test

    Dim Query, Connection, Command, Recordset

    Query = " blah blah blah "

    Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Command = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Connection.ConnectionString = "blah blah blah"
    Connection.Open

    Set Command.ActiveConnection = Connection
    Command.CommandText = Query

    Set Recordset = Command.Execute

    Set Test = Recordset

    Recordset.Close
    Connection.Close

    Set Recordset = Nothing
    Set Command = Nothing
    Set Connection = Nothing

End Function
```

The `Response.Write Count.Fields(0).Value` line yields the `Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.` error.

Replacing it with `Response.Write Count.Status` I get the `Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.` error.

Adding `Count.Open` gives the `The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.` error.

**Edit after Mark B's answer:**

I already looked at disconnected recordsets but I don't know how to use them in my example: every tutorial feeds the query directly into the recordset with `Recordset.Open`, but I'm using parametrized queries, and even trying many ways I couldn't obtain the same result when there's an `ADODB.Command` in the way.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

**Here's the solution based on Eduardo Molteni's answer:**

The function which interacts with the database:

```
Function Test

    Dim Connection, Command, Recordset

    Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Command = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Connection.ConnectionString = "blah blah blah"
    Connection.Open

    Command.ActiveConnection = Connection
    Command.CommandText = "blah blah blah"

    Recordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Recordset.Open Command, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    Set Recordset.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    Set Test = Recordset

    Connection.Close

    Set Recordset = Nothing
    Set Command = Nothing
    Set Connection = Nothing

End Function
```

The code which calls the function:

```
Response.Clear
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

Dim Recordset

Set Recordset = Test

Response.Write Recordset.Fields(0).Value

Recordset.Close

Set Recordset = Nothing
```

Comment: Your final chunk of code is missing `Response.CodePage = 65001`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that returns a disconnected recordset

```
Function RunSQLReturnRS(sqlstmt, params())
    On Error Resume next

    ''//Create the ADO objects
    Dim rs , cmd
    Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

    ''//Init the ADO objects  & the stored proc parameters
    cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString()
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstmt
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 900 

    ''// propietary function that put params in the cmd
    collectParams cmd, params

    ''//Execute the query for readonly
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    If err.number > 0 then
        BuildErrorMessage()
        exit function
    end if

    ''// Disconnect the recordset
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    ''// Return the resultant recordset
    Set RunSQLReturnRS = rs

End Function
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but how can I achieve the same in JScript? I cannot do "rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly" with an empty parameter for the Connection. I get the error "Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object as its source."

Comment: @jpmorin: Sorry but I don't know JScript. Why don't you just keep this function is VBScript? I believe you can have mixed scripts...

Comment: @EduardoMolteni: I have been able to set manually the parameters in the recordset object and call the open method with only the command parameter. I also had to write SET NOCOUNT ON; in my stored procedure to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are closing the recordset and connection immediately after setting the function's return variable, so that explains the error messages.

I am not a VB developer, but I think what you need to look at is Disconnected Recordsets. Take a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134116/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080101-1.shtml), it's doing pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi, I already looked at disconnected recordsets - I should have mentioned it - but I don't know how to use them in my example: every tutorial feeds the query directly into the recordset with `Recordset.Open`, but I'm using parametrized queries, and even trying many ways I couldn't obtain the same result when there's an `ADODB.Command` in the way.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and include all that information, then someone with more VB knowledge than me might be able to help.