# unable to execute query in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Following is the ASP code that I am working on:

```vbs
Dim sConnString, connection, sSQL, backgroundColor
sSQL = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, zip, country, company, industry, revenue, timestamp FROM users"
sConnString=//a connection string
Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.Mode=adModeRead
connection.Open(sConnString)
connection.execute(sSQL)

Response.Write"<table>"
do while not connection.EOF
    if(backgroundColor="#f1f1f1")then
        backgroundColor="#ffffff"
    else
        backgroundColor="#f1f1f1"
    end if

    response.write"<tr backgroundColor="& backgroundColor & "></td>" & connection("firstName") & "</td><td>" & connection("lastName") & "</td><td>" & connection("email") & "</td><td>" & connection("zip") & "</td><td>" & connection("country") & "</td><td>" & connection("company") & "</td><td>" & connection("industry") & "</td><td>" & connection("revenue") & "</td><td>" & connection("timestamp") & "</td></tr>"

    connection.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write"</table>"

connection.Close
Set connection = Nothing
```

I am getting the following error:

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
>
> /wsu.asp, line 13

Line 13:

```
do while not connection.EOF
```

Could you please help me with this?

Updated code:

```
<html>
<body>
<%
Dim sConnString, connection, sSQL, backgroundColor
sSQL = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, zip, country, company, industry, revenue, timestamp FROM users"
sConnString="a connection string for MS SQL database;"
Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
connection.Mode=adModeRead
rs.open sSQL,connection

Response.Write"<table>"
do while not connection.EOF
if(backgroundColor="#f1f1f1")then
backgroundColor="#ffffff"
else
backgroundColor="#f1f1f1"
end if

response.write "<tr backgroundColor="& backgroundColor & "></td>" & connection("firstName") & "</td><td>" & connection("lastName") & "</td><td>" & connection("email") & "</td><td>" & connection("zip") & "</td><td>" & connection("country") & "</td><td>" & connection("company") & "</td><td>" & connection("industry") & "</td><td>" & connection("revenue") & "</td><td>" & connection("timestamp") & "</td></tr>"

connection.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write"</table>"

connection.Close
Set connection = Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to create a recordset and EOF on that - not the connection

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I am a PHP guy, but I had to write this in ASP for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

See the following edit in your code - 
you create a recordset and then open it and execute it

```
<html>
<body>
<%
Dim sConnString, connection, sSQL, backgroundColor,objrs
sSQL = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, zip, country, company, industry, revenue, timestamp FROM users"    
Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.connectionstring = "put your connection string in here"
' replace put your connection string in here with your connection string
Set objrs= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")   
connection.Open()
objrs.open sSQL,connection

Response.Write"<table>"
do while not objrs.EOF
if(backgroundColor="#f1f1f1")then
backgroundColor="#ffffff"
else
backgroundColor="#f1f1f1"
end if

response.write"<tr backgroundColor="& backgroundColor & "></td>" & objrs("firstName") & "</td><td>" & objrs("lastName") & "</td><td>" & objrs("email") & "</td><td>" & objrs("zip") & "</td><td>" & objrs("country") & "</td><td>" & objrs("company") & "</td><td>" & objrs("industry") & "</td><td>" & objrs("revenue") & "</td><td>" & objrs("timestamp") & "</td></tr>"

objrs.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write"</table>"
%>
</body>
</html>
```

a note:--

this needs to be something like - not sure what database you are using -

```
 sConnString= "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatebaseName "
```

or if you have a dsn connection then simply

```
sConnString = "DSN=xxxxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx"
```

Comment: I tried that, but got following error:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch

/wsu.asp, line 21 

Line 21: 
response.write"<tr backgroundColor="& backgroundColor & "></td>" & rs("firstName") & "</td><td>" & rs("lastName") & "</td><td>" & rs("email") & "</td><td>" & rs("zip") & "</td><td>" & rs("country") & "</td><td>" & rs("company") & "</td><td>" & rs("industry") & "</td><td>" & rs("revenue") & "</td><td>" & rs("timestamp") & "</td></tr>"

And in your code, is that suppose to be "objrs.open sSQL,connection" instead of "objrs.open sql,connection" ?

Comment: @rdesai yes it should be ssql . Don't forget to mark it as answer thanks

Comment: ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e7d'

The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.

/testing/wsu.asp, line 10 

Line 10: rs.open sSQL,connection

sSQL = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, zip, country, company, industry, revenue, timestamp FROM users"

I wonder whats wrong.

Comment: are you putting anything in this line - you have to replace a connection string with yours                              sConnString='a connection string

Comment: My connection string is like that as you have mentioned. I am using MS SQL database. Please refer to the updated code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: The problem you are getting is that you cant connect to sql - i looked up the error you had - http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/why-do-i-get-800a0e7d-errors.html - its due to the way you are connecting - i have edited the code again can you copy and paste my code and then replace the connection string with yours and let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `Recordset` to read the data from your SQL query. You have used connection itself.

try below example.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837902/return-recordset-from-function-in-classic-asp)