# Classic ASP Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I have cruised and implemented code from some of the other responses to this question, but I'm still having no luck. I am still getting the error.

```
    If ((bReport And bIsDate And CheckPermissions("lotsales")) Or Request.QueryString("report")) Then
    OpenDB
    Dim oRs, sSQL, sSQL2, iCancellations, iSales, sDate, sInitDate, sEndDate, iPhaseID, iPhaseNumber, rowCount

    sInitDate = Request("startDate")
    sEndDate = Request("endDate")
    sSQL = "sp_get_lot_sales_test '" & sInitDate & "', '" & sEndDate & "', " & sPhase & ", '" & sReportView & "'"

    'response.write vbNewLine & "<!-- sql: " & sSQL & "-->" & vbNewLine
    'response.write sSQL
    'response.Flush
    Set oRs = ExecuteCommand(sSQL,1) 
End If
```

And then here is where the error occurs -

```
If (oRs.EOF) Then <-- fails here
       Response.Write("<TR><TD ALIGN=""center"">There is no data to report on!</TD></TR>")
    Else
        Do While Not oRs.EOF
```

As a last resort I am going to go back to the stored procedure and deconstruct it to make sure all is well there. Does anyone have any insight as to why I might be getting the error? I am not issuing a close anywhere.

Here is the ExecuteCommand function -

```
Function ExecuteCommand(s,i)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ExecuteCommand = oDBc.Execute(s, , i)
End Function
```

Comment: haven't done Classic ASP in many years, but the first thing I'd try is moving the "dim oRs" outside of your if statement.

Comment: That didn't work. I have another file that is set up the same exact way and it works, just calls a different stored procedure. It's code I inherited.

Comment: are you sure the code in the IF block is being executed?

Comment: We need to see the code of `ExecuteCommand` method - something there is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a connection object.

```
set conn = server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
set oRs = conn.execute(sSql)
```

Comment: Did you create a recordset object earlier in your code? It's not just a variable.

Comment: You dim oRs, but I don't see you creating a recordset object in your code: Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Comment: I did that and got the same result. I have tried reconfiguring the connection, have tested this backwards and forwards and cannot get rid of the error. Yet this EXACT code works with another stored procedure so I am deconstructing the SP now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837902/return-recordset-from-function-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 19):

This may be old, but I frequently come across that error (operation is not allowed when object is closed).

What I do is in the stored procedure, I add the follwing:

**SET NOCOUNT ON**

**SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF**

right below the **AS** in the procedure.

That's all I do and the problem goes away.

Comment: Although this "fixes" the problem, the method in which it does it is akin to noticing a warning light on your dash, and then popping the dash and unhooking the wire on that bulb, and now the warning light isn't a problem anymore ..  that being said, do what you gotta do, but keep this in mind later if things start acting weird elsewhere and there is no indication from your SP as to why something is happening strangely.

Answer (score 7):

I am maintaining some old Classic ASP code for a client, code that we took over from a prior developer, and this bug drove me crazy for 4 hours.

I finally discovered a few PRINT statements in the associated SQL stored procedure, which were there for troubleshooting or checking values but don't actually return rows, yet they caused this to fail:

```
Set cnContentDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnContentDB2.Open sString

sSQL = "EXEC YourStoredProc"

Set oRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRS2.Open sSQL, cnContentDB

if not oR2.EOF then   'THIS WAS GIVING THE ERROR,
                      'EVEN THOUGH THE STORED PROC ALWAYS RETURNS RECORDS
```

I removed the Print statements, and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is years old, we still end up here looking for solutions.
The cause of this error for me was that the User did not have Execute permission on the Stored Procedure. Granting Execute permission resolved the error.