# What is a good way to sanitize mysql in an old classic ASP site?

Tags: mysql, security, vbscript, asp-classic, sql-injection

I am the maintainer (but thankfully not the creator) of a very old, very large and very badly written classic ASP site for an electronics manufacturer.

Security is a joke. This is the only thing done to sanitize input before throwing it into the mouth of MySQL:

```vb
Function txtval(data)
    txtval = replace(data,"'","&#39;")
    txtval = trim(txtval)
End Function

productid = txtval(Request.QueryString("id"))
SQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " & productid
Set rs = conn.execute(SQL)
```

Because of that, the site is unfortunately (but perhaps not surprisingly) victim of SQL injection attacks, some of them succesful.

The simple means taken above is not nearly enough. Nor is using `Server.HTMLEncode`. Escaping slashes doesn't help either as the attacks are quite sophisticated:

```
product.asp?id=999999.9+UnIoN+AlL+SeLeCt+0x393133353134353632312e39,0x393133353134353632322e39,0x393133353134353632332e39,0x393133353134353632342e39,0x393133353134353632352e39,0x393133353134353632362e39
```

The url above (an arbitrary attempt taken from the access log) gives the folling response from the site:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.1.42-community]
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

/product.asp, line 14
```

This means that the injection made it through but in this case did not succeed in getting any data. Others do, however.

The site consists of hundreds of ASP files with spaghetti code summing up to many thousands of lines without much structure. Because of that it is not an option to go for parameterized queries. The work would be enormous and error prone as well.

One good thing though is that all input parameters in the code are consistently passed through the `txtval` function, so here is a chance to do it better by augmenting the function. Also, since all SQL calls are done with `conn.execute(SQL)` it is quite straightforward to search and replace with eg. `conn.execute(sanitize(SQL))` so here is a chance to do something about it too.

**Given the circumstances, what are my options to prevent or at least minimize the risc of SQL injection?**

Any input is much appreciated.

**Updates:**

1.
I do understand that parameterized queries is the correct way to handle the problem. I use that myself when I create websites. But given the way the site is built and the size of it, it will take 1-2 months to modify, test and debug it. Even if that is what we end up with (which I doubt) I need to do something right now.

2.
The replacement with the html entity is not a typo. It replaces single quote with its html entity. (I didn't make the code!)

3.
In the specific example above, using CInt(id) would solve the problem, but it could be anything, not only numerical inputs.

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, I know that I am not asking for the correct solution. I knew that from the start. That's why I wrote "Given the circumstances".

But still, filtering inputs for mysql keywords like `select`, `union` etc would at least make it better. Not good, but a little bit better. And this is what I am asking for, ideas to make it a little bit better.

Although I appreciate your comments, telling me that the only good option is to use parameterized queries doesn't really help. *Because I know that already :)*

Comment: I know you've said they're not an option, but please understand it's one of the basics in protecting queries like this from SQL Injection: parameterize the query, eg "Select * from products where id=@Id", and then build/add the ID parameter in code before executing it. It can't put you in any worse shape than you're in already, I'd think. Manually adding scrubbing code everwhere isn't going to be any less labor-intensive or less error-prone.

Comment: Er is that a typo or is it actually replacing with the entity string `&#39;` ?

Comment: Parametrization will fix that, in the specific example above enforcing productid to be numeric would alleviate the problem

Comment: bite the bullet and fix the site properly. band-aid solutions never work in the long run...

Comment: There are no "quick fixes" and like @DavidW said any workaround you try will likely take as long to implement and not be as robust.

Comment: Please see my updates. @MarcB: It's not my decision, and even if we went for it, we would need some kind of better protection until the change was done. BTW, the site is going to be completely rewritten within a year or so. Hence it would be a temporary fix anyway. But sometimes temporary fixes are better than no fixes :)

Comment: Your plight should be used as an advertisement as to why using parameterized queries should be a *starting point*, why security needs to be a concern during development, and not something to be addressed later, tacked on at the end. Numerous times I've seen responses regarding this "i'm not concerned with sql injection right now", or "i'm the only user", or "this is just a project for learning". And fast forward that to the plight you are in: "**it is not an option to go for parameterized queries -- the work would be enormous**").

Comment: You're not going to find any "interim quick fixes" for acres and acres of bad/unsafe code. That's the whole point. Perhaps the real solution is to accelerate the rewrite and invest the resources presently destined for the non-existent "quick fix" into properly written database code in the "new" version of the application.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't give up on parameterized queries. They are the single best tool you can use to protect yourself from SQL Injection. If your plan is to replace all of these calls:

```vb
conn.execute(SQL)
```

to these calls:

```vb
conn.execute(sanitize(SQL))
```

then you're already looking at modifying each interaction with SQL (BTW, don't forget `Command.Execute()` and `Recordset.Open()`, which may also be used to run SQL statements). And since you're already planning on changing these calls, consider calling a custom function to *run the statement*. For example, replace:

```vb
set rs = conn.execute(SQL)
```

with:

```vb
set rs = MyExecute(SQL)
```

and then use your custom function to set up a proper parameterized query using a `Command` object instead. You'll need to cleverly parse the SQL statement in this custom function. Identify the values in the `where` clause, determine their type (perhaps you can query the table schema), and add parameters accordingly. But it can be done.

You can also take this opportunity to sanitize the input. Use a `RegExp` object to quickly strip `[^0-9\.]` from numeric fields, for example.

But there's still the opportunity that you'll return a recordset from this function that will be used to write values directly to the page without being HTML-encoded first. That's a real concern, especially since it sounds like your site has already been targeted in the past. I wouldn't trust any data coming from your database. The only option I see here (that wouldn't involve touching every page) is to return a "clean", HTML-encoded recordset instead of the default one.

Unfortunately, you're still not out of the woods. XSS attacks can be done via QueryString parameters, cookies, and form controls. How safe are you going to feel after "fixing" the SQL Injection issues knowing that XSS is still a very real possibility?

My advice? Explain to your supervisor the security threats plaguing your site and convince him/her the need for a thorough review or a complete rewrite. It may seem like a lot of resources to throw at an "old, already-working website", but the moment someone defaces your website or truncates your database tables, you'll wish you invested the time.

Comment: I have already tried something similar to set rs = MyExecute(SQL), but the recordset returned was not valid. I think ASP does not support objects in function return values.

Comment: @marlar It does support returning objects just remember to use `Set` when returning it `Set MyExecute = rs` *(where `rs` is the `ADODB.Recordset` instantiated inside the `MyExecute()` function)*.

Answer (score 0):

This attack should only affect numeric values passed in your SQL.

There may or may not be a quick fix depending on whether the same `txtval` function is used for both numeric and string values (and others like date too).

If `txtval` is only used for numeric values (probably unlikely) then you could protected by adding single quotes around the value, eg:

```vb
Function txtval(data)
    txtval = replace(data,"'","&#39;")
    txtval = "'" & trim(txtval) & "'"
End Function
```

If it is used for all value types then your only option might be to search through all the code and either:

1) Add single quotes to all numeric SQL, eg:

```vb
SQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '" & productid & "'"
```

2) Create a new function just for sanitizing number values and then change all your queries to use that (not a quick fix), eg:

```vb
Function numval(data)
    If IsNumeric(data) Then
        numvalue = CDbl(data)
    Else
        numvalue = 0 'or NULL?
    End If
End Function
```

And then change your queries, eg:

```vb
productid = numval(Request.QueryString("id"))
SQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " & productid
```

---

Is there common code (ie. in an include file) that is used to open the database and create the `conn` variable used in your sample code?

If so, then you could just replace that code and create your own class with `Open`, `Close` and `Execute` functions (at least). You may need other methods too if they are used in your code.

That way you could effectively override the `execute` in lines like `Set rs = conn.execute(SQL)`.

Eg:

```vb
Class MyDatabase
    Private m_conn

    Public Sub Open(connString)
        Set m_conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        m_conn.Open connString
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        m_conn.Close
        Set m_conn = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Function Execute(sql)
        'Sanitize input here (sql), simple example just for this type of attack
        If InStr(sql, "UnIoN AlL SeLeCt") <> 0 Then sql = ""
        'return a RecordSet
        Set Execute = m_conn.Execute(sql)
    End Property
End Class
```

Then change your common conn declaration from... (eg)

```vb
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

...to...

```vb
Set conn = New MyDatabase
```

---

If you keep the `txtval` function I would also update it to escape slashes as well as single quotes, eg:

```vb
Function txtval(data)
    txtval = Replace(Replace(strValue, "'", "''"), "\", "\\")
    txtval = trim(txtval)
End Function
```

Hopefully something here might be of help.

Comment: txtval() is used for all kinds of input, unfortunately. There is a small common file included with all files that takes care of the data connection. So it is indeed possible to do something here. However, I have already tried making my own execute function, but apparently ASP does not allow functions to return objects, so the recordset (rs in my example) is not valid. How do I handle this problem?

Comment: Hmm... it sounded like a good idea in my head at least. Not aware of any issue with returning an object, as long as `Set` is used. There was another SO question that might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837902/return-recordset-from-function-in-classic-asp

Comment: Just thinking about what other solutions there might be that don't require you to go through lots of Classic ASP files to fix... How about writing your own ISAPI filter?

Comment: Thanks for the update about using Set. Can you elaborate a bit on the ISAPI filter? I know what a ISAPI filter is but would like a comment on how it can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Create an ISAPI filters that runs for all .asp files and looks for common SQL injection methods and if found redirects, filters or ends the request. There seems to be quite a few tutorials online for creating and using filters.