# How do I write this IF statement within my ASP page?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to display an image on website only if a value in the database is true. I'm using the below code as a template (which is currently working) as my guide, though mine is simpler. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<% strSQL4 = valid SQL statement
   set r4 = d2.execute(strSQL4)
   if (r4.EOF = False) and (r4.BOF = False) then
   else
       r4.moveFirst
       while (r4.EOF = False) and (r4.BOF = False) %>
<li><%= r4("Database Field") %></li>
<% r4.movenext
   wend
   end if %>
```

That is the code I'm basically emulating, but I'm just trying to display an image if a bool variable is true in a database, per my code below:

```
<%# ACTLBool = "SELECT ACTL FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ATTY_ID = " & AttorneyID
   if (ACTLBool = True) then %>
<div id="ACTLDiv"><img id="ACTLLogo" src="img/ACTL.jpg" alt="ACTL Logo" /> </div>
<%# else end if %>
```

I don't need it to do anything if the ACTLBool is false. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're fetching the data from a database you'll need some sort of recordset (r4 in your template). ACTLBool will not be _true_, it will be a string containing your SQL.

Comment: The ACTL field in my database is a Yes/No field. Okay, that makes some sense, how would I pull the boolean value after getting a recordset?

Comment: I mean, it seems like it would be r4.getsomething or r4.ACTL.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_recordset.asp may be a useful reference here if you are using ADO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837902/return-recordset-from-function-in-classic-asp may also be a useful link.

Comment: It looks like I can use the rs.Fields.Item property, but I'm not sure. I gave it a spin, but still didn't work.

Comment: What is this? Don't recognise the syntax `<%#`?? You sure this isn't ASP.Net? looks like data-binding syntax.

Answer (score 0):

assuming conn is your adodb.connection object

```
Dim rs : set rs = conn.execute("SELECT count(ACTL) as c FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ATTY_ID = " & CLng(AttorneyId))
If rs("c") > 0 Then
    response.write "<div id='ACTLDiv'><img id='ACTLLogo' src='img/ACTL.jpg' alt='ACTL Logo' /> </div>"
End If
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Hey @frumbert, I'm a little confused as to why you are counting a "Yes/No" field in the database.

Comment: Well @Joseph , since I don't know your database, ACTL could have been any type of field. I guess I missed `SELECT count(ACTL) as c FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ACTL=true AND ATTY_ID = " & CLng(AttorneyId)` to catch only a true state (e.g. `c` = 0 when niether true for a matching `ATTY_ID`  or when `ATTY_ID` doesn't match a record), so you can avoid a EOF/BOF test.

Comment: In my original post, I showed that ACTL was a bool variable, which is either true or false.

Comment: well, it wasn't super clear on my first pass when I put this out there.